# how to Show tooltips in angular

Tags: angular, syncfusion

I am using Angular 7, Syncfusion UI Components for our application.
In the below link i have implemented the custom tooltip and it is working fine for HTML Table 
[Sample stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-santhosh-tooltip?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

And i have implemented same in our Application
Please see the below stackbltz link
[Sample stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-syncfusiongrid-date-filter)

**My issue is how to show the tooltips for all the columns in ejs-grid. In the first column i have implemented using ng-template, but with out using ng-template i have implemented for remaining columns and it is not working.**
kindly let me know how to resolve this.

Comment: what is the issue if you `ng-template`?

Comment: No problem. Actually in tooltip.directive.ts  i am  creating span tag like this.renderer.createElement('span'); . How to use ViewContainerRef to create the tooltip and destroy it.

Answer (score 0):

We have already discuss about your query “Need to set tooltip for columns” in the following documentation.

Link: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/grid/how-to/custom-tool-tip-for-columns/

Please let us know if you need further assistance.

Regards,

Thavasianand S.

Comment: using querycellinfo(--) tooltip is showing but filtering and sorting and not working as   By default while using the queryCellInfo event then the event will be triggered for every grid actions( filtering, paging, sorting etc.,). While using data(45) with columns(8) then it might cause the reported problem (web page hang) because of rendering tooltip( 45 *8 = 360) in queryCellInfo event.